# Expanding sidebar menu. How they did it?

Tags: css

http://pointnorth.io

How did they make the expanding sidebar on the left? It seems like it's css only but I might be wrong.

There's the main url and then the other ones are all preceeded by #, the text is all on one page and then it expands or hide when clicked.

I don't understand how they hide or display data.

Comment: Have you looked at the page source?

Comment: @ialarmedalien of course. I asked because I didn't understand the code.

Comment: They use javascript and css to show and hide the text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not only CSS. This page in bottom of body has javascript code, which sets data-active attribute for link, which was be clicked. As you can see, data-active made section of sub items with height: auto. In other cases .nav--sub-sections class has height: 0px.

Comment: Are you sure? I deleted the 'script' node (F12 > Elements > deleted '<script>...</script>') from the chrome console and it was still working regardless.

Comment: It doesn't matter, script was loaded and working regardless your deletion.

Comment: Please, read this article http://ablogaboutcode.com/2011/06/14/how-javascript-loading-works-domcontentloaded-and-onload/

Answer (score 0):

You can easily implement your own without lifting someone else's idea.Look at this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/vfrcx678/ and how it goes here http://jsfiddle.net/vfrcx678/show/

This is some sample code

```
$(window).hashchange({
    hash: "#!/login/",
    onSet: function() {
        $("#login-form").show();
    },
    onRemove: function() {
        $("#login-form").hide();
    },
});
```

Project page https://github.com/apopelo/jquery-hashchange

Comment: Thanks. It doesn't work for me though. I'll download the code from github and have a look.